AWS: How to let a S3 frontend (React, Axios) communicate with an EC2 backend (python3/Django, DjangoREST, corsheaders)
I followed a tutorial for creating a basic To-Do app (so CRUD) with a React+Axios frontend (ServiceWorker, bootstrap) and Django backend (DjangoREST, corsheaders), and would like to put it on AWS's free tier for job-finding purposes. I got the app running fine locally using localhost, and even able to get the server running on EC2 and the frontend hosted on S3 using various other tutorials. Now i'm stuck on how to get them to communicate without them being on the same machine. I had hoped I could just change some lines relating to localhost to their IP's and Ports, but that hasn't worked. Since this is a fairly simple example program I tried to keep security to a minimum throughout setup to help communications, and have allowed HTTP and HTTPS and anything I could * in my security settings. In settings.py I have:
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = ['http://frontend-IP:3000']

and in my frontend package.json I have:
"proxy": "http://backend-IP:80",

to tunnel the API to the backend so my axios commands look like:
axios
      .get("/api/todos/")

Rather than the whole address. I also am not sure how to make React use something other than localhost:3000 or if i need to change that if its on S3 fine? I tried to test it locally with cross-env, .env, and adding HOST to the package.json but after fiddling it actually damage my ability to npm start the server to the point i had to revert versions.
I don't have an Elastic Load Balancer on AWS unless i missed that option somewhere setting things up, is that part of it? I'm also a bit lost on if any certs are needed here, as I've never deployed an app that had to talk over internet.
I expected hosting on S3 and EC2 would allow me to just change the aforementioned lines to eachother's IP's and ports so they could communicate and perform CRUD operations on Django's db.sqlite3 file.
EDIT: I added an elastic IP to the EC2 through AWS and changed my Axios commands to point to the new IP, but it seems like nothing has changed. I'm wondering if there is just a pointer somewhere that i'm missing.

Your GET /api/todos/ will be sent to the same domain that served up the HTML page, which is S3. To send that request to a different domain (your EC2 instance), you need to explicitly indicate the domain e.g. GET http://my-ec2-host/api/todos/. The web server on your EC2 host will also need to use CORS to allow the cross-domain request from the web page served from your S3 bucket.

@jarmod thank you for the response! For clarification, is that last part different than the CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST i mentioned in my settings.py on EC2? or do i need to add something like {Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '*'} ?

If I were implementing this solution, I would look at using Serverless solution. Instead of hacking around with EC2 and makign that work with HTTPs (which is necessary once you deploy your React app), I would do React->API Gateway -> Lambda -> AWS Services.

@smac2020 thanks and you are probably right, but due to certain personal constraints I have to use EC2 as the backend django server. I also made sure to allow HTTPS traffic when setting up security for the EC2/VPC and it is fully public.

No, that seems right. Note that CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST is an older setting and has been renamed, and is now aliased, to CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS.

@jarmod OK so I changed your suggestions and tried to run the frontend locally, but it still gave this following error that seems to say they arent talking:
AxiosError: Network Error
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:47477:14)
    at Axios.request (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:47915:41)```

Why does localhost appear in the error message? Isn't your web page served from S3 and your EC2 API server hosted in EC2, neither of which is localhost?

@jarmod I tried to run it locally on my machine to see if it would access the EC2, thats why. I just made a new frontend build with the changes and deployed it to S3 and its doing the same thing where it looks fine, but if i try to add an item with CRUD nothing happens. though on S3 there is no popup error.

some other contextual info, I did add some CORS wildcards to the S3 bucket using amazons interface to try and cut off errors wherever possible. Currently my django server is running on port 80 because i read that it was open in EC2, and at the IP address i found in IPConfig. This IP is also where I pointed all my Axios requests.
